# SAP Hybris - DataHub - 400 Bad Request y2ySyncYaaS

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I am trying to sync my YaaS configurations from the backoffice.I get a 400  error

`

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/01/20 00:00:09.408 | [m[32mINFO  [TaskExecutor-master-544956-Task [8812098257846]] [ProcessChangesTask] Created SyncImpExMediaModel >>>> SyncImpExMediaModel (8897965031454@1) [syncExecutionID: 00006NUA]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/01/20 00:00:09.708 | [m[32mINFO  [TaskExecutor-master-544961-Task [8812098454454]] [DefaultExportService] Export was successful (using cronjob with code=00006NUH)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/01/20 00:00:09.808 | [m[32mINFO  [TaskExecutor-master-544961-Task [8812098454454]] [ProcessChangesTask] Created SyncImpExMediaModel >>>> SyncImpExMediaModel (8897965293598@1) [syncExecutionID: 00006NU9]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/01/20 00:00:09.909 | [m[32mINFO  [TaskExecutor-master-544961-Task [8812098454454]] [ProcessChangesTask] Created SyncImpExMediaModel >>>> SyncImpExMediaModel (8897965359134@1) [syncExecutionID: 00006NU9]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/01/20 00:00:10.309 | [m[32mINFO  [TaskExecutor-master-544969-Task [8812098487222]] [DataHubRequestCreator] Sending request to datahub @ http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/datahub-webapp/v1/y2ysync/v60 with sync execution id: 00006NU9
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/01/20 00:00:10.309 | [m[1;31mERROR [TaskExecutor-master-544969-Task [8812098487222]] [DataHubRequestTaskRunner] 400 Bad Request
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/01/20 00:00:10.309 | [m org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/01/20 00:00:10.309 |     at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/01/20 00:00:10.309 |     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:667) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/01/20 00:00:10.309 |
```

`

Here is my datahub config  :

`

```
  datahubadapter.datahuboutbound.url=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/datahub-webapp/v1
  y2ysync.datahub.url=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/datahub-webapp/v1/y2ysync/v60
  y2ysync.batch.size=10000
  y2ysync.datahub.upload.retries=3
```

`

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running into the same problem, what worked for me is:

- Putting the right values (Pool , feed , target system) on the export definition
  [image]
- Setting export url to EMPTY on the export job

  [image]